# “invalid security certificate” (ssl_error_bad_cert_domain) after PFX uploaded to Azure

Tags: ssl, azure

My SSL certificate (purchased on godaddy) on Azure stopped working all of a sudden. I am running a standard Azure website and I previously uploaded a .pfx file and bound my custom domain to it. However, two days ago the cert stopped working.

I re-keyed the certificate (on godaddy) with a new CSR generated through IIS 7 and imported both the certificate and its intermediate certificates from godaddy. After that I exported the pfx with the private key and uploaded that to azure. My custom domain platform.qochi.com is pointing to my azurewebsite and I have updated the A record to be the IP address of my azure website.

Someone help please. I am at a lost on whats going on and why this is failing me

Comment: `ssl_error_bad_cert_domain` normally means the domain on the certificate does not match the domain requested in the browswer. But, I just visited the domain you provided, and the certificate validates for me. Can you revisit it and see if it's resolved?

Comment: It magically resolved itself. Not sure what was the cause, but its fixed.